# Master's studies in France and Greece (one year per country) plausibility

Tags: graduate-school, france, abroad, greece

This might sound a bit ridiculous, but I would love to spend a year in Greece and France and I think my master's studies might be a great time for that. However, I am not sure how plausible such an idea would be. Assuming I were to go to Greece first and apply to a French university for my second year, will I just need to ensure that the syllabus taken at the Greek university is compatible with the French one? I haven't thought through many of the details so this is the only issue that jumps out to me, are there any other problems I should be concerned with?

Comment: There are many universities in the EU offering joint degrees of this sort. Enrolling in one of those is a much better idea. However, availability of course depends on what you want to study and where, does it absolutely have to be France and Greece for example?

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the response! I definitely want to go to Greece and France. Should I just look up various universities and look for joint degrees, or is there another way to find such programs? I also heard of Erasmus programs, is that similar to what you are talking about?

Comment: The Erasmus program is another option, that would allow you to be enrolled at one university and then spend one or two semesters at another, where ideally the credit you receive counts towards your degree at the first university. This is of course more flexible but keep in mind that every university has a limited set of "partner" Erasmus universities and getting a spot is not guaranteed. I suggest you find a degree that interests you and then ask the university about their exchange program.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the information! I'll contact some universities to find out more :)

Answer (score 2):

If your plan is to live in each country one year, you would be better off by doing a master course of 2 years in Greece (or France) and being one year exchange student with Erasmus program in France (or Greece).

As far as I know, you can be Erasmus student without scholarship (which means you will fund yourself through the abroad stay).

Bureaucracy can be complicated (transcript of exams must be translated, syllabus not matching, etcetc) but being under the umbrella of the Erasmus Programm will help you a lot.